# time data 'June 13, 1980 (United States)' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How can i passs a datetime format on a column with str such as `June 13, 1980 (United States)`

i tried  `df['format_released'] = pd.to_datetime(df['released'], format='%m/%d/%Y')`

got this error

> time data 'June 13, 1980 (United States)' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preprocess the column to discard the non relevant data.

Using `str.replace`:

```
df['format_released'] = pd.to_datetime(df['released'].str.replace(r'\s*(.*$', '', regex=True), format='%B %d, %Y')
```

Or using `str.extract`:

```
df['format_released'] = pd.to_datetime(df['released'].str.extract(r'(\w+ \d+, \d+)', expand=False), format='%B %d, %Y')
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct format is: `pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(df['released'], format='%B %d, %Y')`

For the full name, you need to specify %B for the format.
You don't need the value "(United States)" in the string.

Comment: it will throw this error `ValueError: unconverted data remains:  (United States)`, because it's a column. not a single string

Comment: i just provide a example for one row